# If $f'(x)=0$, is then $f(x+dx)=f(x)$?

Tags: real-analysis, infinitesimals, convex-hulls

I am always struggling with infinitesimals, and not sure I'm getting this right. The title basically states the simplest version of my question: If a function has zero slope at some point, is it correct to say that $f(x)=f(x+dx)$ for an infinitesimally small $dx$?
-- If yes, can anyone intuitively explain why I can drop the other terms of the Taylor expansion here?

**Edit:** It has been pointed out that "infinitesimal" really isn't a well-defined concept in the way that I've used it here, and the answer by Seth explains why. I've clarified what I'm after (without the use of "infinitesimals" in a [separate question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2978152/how-does-the-optimum-of-a-convex-optimization-respond-to-a-change-in-the-externa) to avoid mixing too many different problems under one header.

Comment: Can you explain a bit better what you mean by "infinitesimal"?

Comment: Since you tagged this "real-analysis", you should try to make clear what you actually *mean* by such a statement. After all, in the real number system, there are no (nonzero) infinitesimals!

Comment: That's my problem.. I often see this notation used in papers for "small enough" changes, but I don't know exactly what it means to have an "infinitesimally small" change. Is there an official definition of what an "infinitesimal" is?

Comment: Consider $f(x)=x^2$ at $x=0$. Then $f'(0)=0$ but no non-zero $x$ satisfies $f(x)=0$. As for your second question, consider the convex hull $X$ generated by $(1/n,1/n^2)$ for $n\in\mathbb{Z}\setminus\{0\}$ and $(0,0)$. Then the only supporting hyperplane at $(0,0)$ is the line $y=0$, but no non-zero element of this set lies in $X$.

Comment: @Gibbs and others: Thank you all for pointing out my vague language. Indeed, it's precisely the fuzziness of the term that is giving me pause, and despite having seen it used, I don't really know what is meant by an "infinitesimal". I've updated the question to describe what I'm really trying to say, but am unable to formally state. If any of you can help, that'd be hugely appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the hyperreal number system defined by Robinson, which is a common context in which infinitesimals can be rigorously defined, a function $f$ is differentiable at $x$ if there is a real number $f'(x)$ such that $$f'(x)\approx\frac{f(x+\epsilon)-f(x)}{\epsilon}$$ for all infinitesimals $\epsilon$. Here, $a\approx b$ means that $a$ and $b$ differ by an infinitesimal.

Thus, if $f$ is differentiable at $x$, this implies that $$\frac{f(x +dx)-f(x)}{dx}=f'(x)+\eta$$ for some infinitesimal $\eta$, which implies that $$f(x+dx)-f(x)=dx\,(f'(x)+\eta).$$ Since $dx$ is infinitesimal, the right side is infinitesimal, and therefore, in our alternative notation, $f(x+dx)\approx f(x)$.

Interestingly, this is the definition of continuity: $f$ is continuous at $x$ if $f(x+\epsilon)\approx f(x)$ for all infinitesimals $\epsilon$. Thus the above argument shows that differentiability implies continuity.

The hypothesis $f'(x)=0$ was not used above.  This stronger hypothesis means that $$\frac{f(x+dx)-f(x)}{dx}\approx 0,$$ which means intuitively that $f(x+dx)-f(x)$ is so small that even after dividing it by the infinitesimal $dx$, it is still infinitesimal.

Comment: Thank you, especially for the explanation of how to understand infinitesimals in terms of the operator $\approx$. That makes a lot more sense now. I've upvoted your answer, but unfortunately it doesn't really help me get anywhere with my underlying problem (see update). If you don't mind, I'll wait a bit to see if someone can help there before formally accepting an answer and closing the question.

Comment: To avoid making a mess of this question, I've accepted your solution as it answers the title and gives great intuition. I've moved the problem of formalizing my conjecture into a separate question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2978152/how-does-the-optimum-of-a-convex-optimization-respond-to-a-change-in-the-externa and will update the question to reflect this.

Answer (score -2):

Suppose $f$ continuous differentiable at $x$, as it stated by the $f'(x)=0$. In the case or Riemann integral.

$f'(x)=0\Rightarrow \lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=0
\Rightarrow \frac{f(x+dx)-f(x)}{dx}=0\Rightarrow f(x+dx)-f(x)=0$.

Also $dx$ is not a number in the sence of real(in Riemann or differential geometry), it's more like an operator represtation. 
In a sense that "it never goes to anywhere". Suppose $m,n\in\mathbb{N}$, $m+dx"="m$, $m+n*dx"="m$ yet $0< m*n*dx<<1$. ($"="$ means "sort of equal" in real, but notice this is very improper.)

For your question, answering in the case of real analysis, I think $f'(x)$ exists, which is differentiable at $x$, already implied that $f$ is continuous at $x$.

Therefore, for anly $\epsilon>0$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that whenever $|x_{new}-x|<\delta$, $|f(x_{new})-f(x)|<\epsilon$. Thus $f("x+dx")=f(x)$.

Comment: I see how that's the case, but I'm just not familiar enough with infinitesimals, I think. Here's what confuses me: If for example $x=0$, $f(x)=x^2$, then it's also true that $f(dx)=dx^2$, which is positive for all $dx$ (no matter how small).

Comment: @mimuller $dx$ is not a number, you can't thinkg about an order relation by add it with real or complex. You can't compare them litterately.

Comment: Is there a formal definition of that order relation? That's exactly where I get confused I think. (Btw, I'm not downvoting, but some people seem to really disagree with you...)

Comment: @mimuller you see, that's the issue here, $dx$ have different definition in real analysis based on the integerateion techneque you are using, for example, if it's Riemann or not, and it's improper to write it alone. But in engineer or physics, people only cared about the linearlization or it's order, in the sense of small changes in differential geometry. Since you are definately not talking aobut tensor, my answer is that you shuout quite writting $dx$, instead, write formally with $\delta$ and $\epsilon$. Otherwise you won't go anywhere.

Comment: Thank you for elaborating, this is really useful! I've updated the question to illustrate what I'm trying to say... unfortunately, it's exactly with the translation into $\delta$ and $\epsilon$ that I'm stuck... but I'll think more about it!

Comment: @mimuller see my answer, the differentiability was not necessary. By writting in $\epsilon$ and $\delta$,  in real analysis, it's acturally just the definition of continunity.