# How does the optimum of a convex optimization respond to a change in the external parameter?

Tags: derivatives, convex-optimization

Consider the optimization problem $max_{x\in X} f(x,k)$, where

- $X\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ is compact and convex
- $k$ may be vector valued,
- $f(x,k)$ is differentiable in both parameters and concave.
- (In my specific problem, $f(x,k)=\sum_{i=1}^n k_i \ln x_i$.)

Because the problem is convex, we know that there is always a unique optimum $x^*(k)$, and by [Berge's Theorem of the maximum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_theorem) it varies continuously with $k$. My question is whether we know anything about the direction in which the optimum moves?

The Lagrangian approach is useful as long as $X$ can be described by finitely many inequalities (via the Jacobian $\partial x^*/\partial k$), but I get stuck for more complicated sets (e.g. the convex hull of a countable collection of points). Intuitively, it seems that when we "tilt" the level curves of $f$ at $x^*(k)$ along a direction that is contained in all supporting hyperplanes at $x^*(k)$, then we should ``slide along the surface'' in the direction of the tilt... but I'm having trouble formalizing the idea, and therefore evaluating its veracity.

Comment: a convex sphere around $c$ with radius $r$ can be defined with just one inequality: $||x-c|| \leq r$

Comment: @LinAlg True! I meant "linear inequality". What I had in mind was $X$ being a regular convex polytope... but I don't know how to generalize it when $X$ is the convex hull over countably many points. I've updated the question to reflect that better.

Comment: still not a problem, you can write $x = \sum_i \lambda_i x^i$ with $x^i$ the points of which the convex hull is taken ($\lambda$ in the standard simplex). Carathéodory's theorem limits the number of nonzero $\lambda_i$.

Comment: @LinAlg: I agree, but that doesn't explain what happens when $k$ changes, does it? The points could be densely distributed on a sphere, then $\lambda$ has only one positive entry, but it's a different one for every $k$. So I don't see how that's helping with the answer...

Comment: your $f$ is concave in $x$ (which is good for maximizing $f$)

Comment: @daw Yes, sorry.. I always get myself confused with the language. :) The upper contour sets are convex.